# How can I give objects acending numbers

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have a class documents , that creates documents for a search engine. The object of the class Document should have  ascending IDs. This means that the first document that was created has documentId 0, the second document has documentId 1. This is supposed to be happening in the constructor, but I am not quite sure how to start.
[The class Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMaVn.png)

Comment: Keep a static ID and increment it? Please post code as formatted text, not as links to pictures of text.

Comment: You need to put your code in the question itself. Don't link us to images of code -- nobody can copy-paste the code out of a picture! (And some of us can't even see imgur at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a `static int variable` that starts at -1 and get incremented by 1 in the constructor. then for each object created that number will go up by 1 since its a class `static` variable. what's left to do is to assign that number to your object variable field ID.

```
public class Document {

    private static int count = -1;
    private int ID;

    public Document() {

        this.count++;
        this.ID = count;
        System.out.println(this.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me understanding it